# O gcc não é encontrado quando o Makefile é executado pelo Travis-CI

Tags: c, linux, makefile, travis-ci

Eu tenho um projeto em C no GitHub e estou tentando realizar o build com Travis-CI, mas sempre é exibido o erro abaixo:

```bash
Using worker: worker-linux-9-2.bb.travis-ci.org:travis-linux-2
$ export CC=gcc
git.1
$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=someDevs git://github.com/luizfilipe/ffb-cglib.git     luizfilipe/ffb-cglib
Cloning into 'luizfilipe/ffb-cglib'...
remote: Counting objects: 114, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (93/93), done.
remote: Total 114 (delta 27), reused 80 (delta 12)
Receiving objects: 100% (114/114), 2.53 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (27/27), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
$ cd luizfilipe/ffb-cglib
git.3
$ git checkout -qf f76cd622418a75003d1aa6326c38039c1f556ee8
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
$ make
gcc -c -pendantic examples/environment/main.c -I/usr/bin/Mesa-5.0/include -g
make: gcc: Command not found
make: *** [main.o] Error 127
The command "make" exited with 2.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Lendo o erro eu notei que o `gcc` não foi encontrado, mas o arquivo `.travis.yml` está configurado conforme abaixo:

```
language: c
compiler:
   - gcc
script: make
```

O `Makefile` do projeto é:

```
# Variables
MESA = /usr/bin/Mesa-5.0
PATH = examples/environment/main
EXAMPLE_ENVIRONMENT = examples/environment/main.c
INCPATH = -I$(MESA)/include
LIBPATH = -L$(MESA)/lib
LIBS        = -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lm
CFLAGS  = $(INCPATH) -g
LFLAGS  = $(LIBPATH) $(LIBS)

# Main targets
all: main.o
    $(CC) -o $(PATH) main.o $(LFLAGS)

# Source targets
main.o: $(EXAMPLE_ENVIRONMENT)
    $(CC) -c -pendantic $(EXAMPLE_ENVIRONMENT) $(CFLAGS)
```

Alguma ideia do que possa estar causando o erro?

Comment: O erro também pode ser verificado em [#18](https://travis-ci.org/luizfilipe/ffb-cglib/builds/18945815)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É boa prática fazer um Makefile que não dependa de um compilador específico. No seu caso, você usou explicitamente o `gcc` para compilar, sempre. Em vez disso, pegue o *compilador padrão de C* da variável de ambiente `CC`. Se você reparar no log, o travis seta essa variável no começo.

O Makefile ficará assim:

```make
# ...

# Main targets
all: main.o
    $(CC) -o $(PATH) main.o $(LFLAGS)

# Source targets
main.o: $(EXAMPLE_ENVIRONMENT)
    $(CC) -c -pendantic $(EXAMPLE_ENVIRONMENT) $(CFLAGS)
```

---

Outro erro está em redefinir a variável `PATH`. Ela é usada pelo sistema para localizar onde os executáveis estão. No momento que você alterou, o sistema não mais será capaz de encontrar o caminho absoluto para o `gcc`. Simplesmente renomeie a variável e tudo deve funcionar.

Comment: Atualizei os arquivos e o problema ainda persiste, atualizei também a pergunta com o erro e os novos arquivos, alguma idéia?

Comment: @LuizFilipe, atualizei a resposta. Só cuidado ao atualizar questões para evitar descontextualizar respostas já existente

Comment: Não tinha percebido o erro! Obrigado pelo alerta! :)